# Using lagrange multiplier to find maximum of $f(p_1, ..., p_n, \lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i + \lambda \left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i - c\right)$

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to find the $p_i$ and $\lambda$ values that maximize the function
$$f(p_1, ..., p_n, \lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i + \lambda \left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i - c\right)$$ such that $p_i > 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = c$.

Using Lagrange multiplier, we have
$$log f(p_1, ..., p_n, \lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^n log p_i + \lambda \left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i - c\right)$$
I first try to solve for $p_i$
$$\frac{\partial log f}{\partial p_i} = \frac{1}{p_i} + \lambda $$
I set the above expression to 0 and solve for $p_i$
$$\Rightarrow p_i = -\frac{1}{\lambda}$$.
Using the constraint, $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = c$, we have that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = -\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda} = c$$
$$\Rightarrow \lambda = -\frac{n}{c}
$$
$$\Rightarrow p_i = \frac{c}{n}$$

However, I don't think this is correct. $\lambda = (-\frac{c}{n})^{n-1}$ is a maximum of the function $f$, not $\lambda = -\frac{n}{c}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p_i = \frac{c}{n}$, then the product would be $\left( \frac{c}{n}\right)^n$.

We know the result is correct from [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Edit:

Suppose we work with the original function directly, taking partial derivative with $p_i$ gives us

$$\prod_{j \ne i}p_j + \lambda =0$$

Multiply $p_i$ gives us $$\prod_{j=1}^n p_j =-\lambda p_i$$

Hence all the $p_i$ are equal and hence $$-{p_1}^{n-1}=\lambda$$

or $$-\left( \frac{c}{n}\right)^{n-1}=\lambda$$

Comment: Thank you @Siong Thye Goh. Yes, I know $p_i = \frac{c}{n}$; however, I'm not sure how to get the correct $\lambda$, which is $(-\frac{c}{n})^{n-1}$

Comment: Note that you are reusing the notation $\lambda$ for two different settings. One with $\log f$, one with $f$. Your $\lambda$ corresponding to the new working with $\log f$ is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to maximize $\prod p_i$ given that $\sum p_i = c$ which is equivalent to maximizing $\log (\prod p_i) = \sum \log p_i$ given that $\sum p_i = c$. So, the new objective function is $\sum \log p_i + \lambda (\sum p_i - c).$ The rest is standar calculation.